# Can't download dj-database-url---django app on heroku

Tags: django, heroku

Trying to get started with Django. My tutorial tells me to run pip install dj-database-url. When I do that, I get:

```
postgres@precise64:/vagrant/projects2/microblog$ pip install dj-database-url
Downloading/unpacking dj-database-url
Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement dj-database-url
No distributions at all found for dj-database-url
Storing complete log in /var/lib/postgresql/.pip/pip.log
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just tried, and it looks to work fine. Open `/var/lib/postgresql/.pip/pip.log` and see what it says

Comment: Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/dj-database-url: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/dj-database-url when looking for download links for dj-database-url  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 948, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 152, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for dj-database-url

Comment: Have you tried downloading the tarball and unpacking it yourself?

Comment: Okay, I've downloaded and unpacked it.  Not sure I put it in the right directory.  How do I make sure my app knows it is there?